# Adding elements to Struct Array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct

```
struct GENERATIONS
{
char generation[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
int hasCycle;
};

typedef struct GENERATIONS Generation;
```

I have an array of type struct:

```
Generation generations[MAX_GENERATIONS];
```

I declare a `Generation`variable like this:

```
Generation *currentGeneration = NULL;
currentGeneration = (Generation *) malloc(sizeof(Generation));
```

and attempt to add a generation to an array of generations: numGenerations is set to 0 then incremented via a loop.

```
copyGeneration(currentGeneration);
generations[numGenerations] = currentGeneration;
```

Yet each time, I get the error incompatible types when assigning to type 'Generation' from type 'struct Generation *. I understand this has to do with pointers which I do not understand but need.

Why is it that when I declare the array as:

```
Generation *generations[MAX_GENERATIONS];
```

Everything suddenly works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `currentGeneration` is a pointer to a `Generation`. Yet when you declare an array `Generation generations[MAX_GENERATIONS]` it expects each index to **be** a `Generation`, not a pointer to one. But when you declare the array as `Generation *generations[MAX_GENERATIONS]` it expects each index to be a pointer to a `Generation`, which is what you are assigning to each index.

Comment: that makes sense, when I was testing getting elements from the generations array, I would create a new generation (as shown above) and do  `g = generations[0]`. I was then able to use g to access all the "objects" data with out using the  `&` to dereference it, why is that?

Comment: Did you access with `->`? That's how you access data on a struct pointer. e.g. `g->hasCycle`.

Comment: yeah that is exactly how I did it

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. Your variable `currentGeneration` is of type "pointer to Generation", and your variable `generations` is of type "array of Generation". You can't assign a pointer to Generation to an index of an array of Generation--you can only assign a Generation.

When you declare the array as `Generation *generations[MAX_GENERATIONS]`, everything works because you're assigning a pointer to Generation to an index of an array of pointers to Generation.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you can proceed in a different way. What you can do is this

```
#define MAX_GENERATIONS 1024 // you can take some other value too
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static int count = 0

Generation** push(Generation** generations, Generation obj){
 count++;
 if (count == MAX_GENERATIONS){
   printf("Maximum limit reached\n");
   return generations;

 if ( count == 1 )
   generations = (Generation**)malloc(sizeof(Generation*) * count);
 else
   generations = (Generation**)realloc(generations, sizeof(Generation*) * count);

 generations[count - 1] = (Generation*)malloc(sizeof(Generation));
 generations[count - 1] = obj;

 return generations;
}

int main(){
  Generation** generations = NULL;
  Generation currentGeneration;
  // Scan the the elements into currentGeneration
  generations = push(generations, currentGeneration); // You can use it in a loop
}
```

Comment: as good as this looks, it seems a bit advanced and my prof may know that it came from a source other than me. I will say thank you an I will try this in the future!

Comment: Okay no prob..but the objective is that you understand the logic here..and if possible help me in my reputation by up voting it..

Answer (score 0):

`currentGeneration` is a `Generation *`, not a `Generation`.

You need an array of `Generation *` to hold it, not an array of `Generation`.